# Translating a C++ function to PHP riddle involving log functions

Tags: php, c++

This is a C++ to PHP riddle involving log functions.

I need to translate the following function into PHP ... It's a long story, but we are sure we have a lot of it figured out ... but I could use another pair of eyes.

I have a possible PHP implementation below ...

We have examples of data on the C++ side that produce checksums that we cannot reproduce on the PHP side ... frustrating.

============================================================

```
#define SYNC_CHECKSUM_MULT (0x01000193)

/**
 * Calculate a reasonable checksum for floating point numbers.
 */
static void oi_AccumulateFloat64Checksum(oiInt& checksum, oiFloat64 f)
{
    // j = round(f * 2^k), where j is a 12-bit number

    if ( oi_IsNaN(f) || oi_IsInf(f) )
    {
        checksum ^= 1;
        checksum *= SYNC_CHECKSUM_MULT;
        return;
    }

    oiInt exponent = (oiInt)logb(f);

    oiInt k = 12 - exponent;

    oiFloat64 jUnrounded = scalb(f, k);

    oiFloat64 jRounded = floor(jUnrounded + 0.5);

    oiInt kChange = (oiInt)logb(jRounded) - 12;

    k += kChange;

    oiFloat64 jFloat = scalb(jRounded, kChange);

    oiInt j = (oiInt)jFloat;

    checksum ^= j;
    checksum *= SYNC_CHECKSUM_MULT;

    checksum ^= k;
    checksum *= SYNC_CHECKSUM_MULT;
}
```

============= PHP Implementation =========================

This is executed before we call this function.. $intChecksum = 0;

```
public function AccumulateFloatChecksum(&$intChecksum, $floatValue) {
    // j = round(f * 2^k), where j is a 12-bit number

    $TRIVIAL_CHECKSUM_MULT = 0x01000193;

    if ( !is_numeric($floatValue) || $floatValue == 0 || is_nan($floatValue) || is_infinite($floatValue) )
    {
        $intChecksum ^= 1;
        $intChecksum *= $TRIVIAL_CHECKSUM_MULT;
        $intChecksum &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
        return;
    }

    //var_dump('$floatValue: '.$floatValue);

    // oiInt exponent = (oiInt)logb(f);
    $exponent = intval(log($floatValue, 2));

    //var_dump('$exponent: '.$exponent);

    // oiInt k = 12 - exponent;
    $k = 12 - $exponent;

    //var_dump('$k 1: '.$k);

    // oiFloat64 jUnrounded = scalb(f, k);
    $jUnrounded = $floatValue * pow(2, $k);

    //var_dump('$jUnrounded: '.$jUnrounded);

    // oiFloat64 jRounded = floor(jUnrounded + 0.5);
    $jRounded = floor($jUnrounded + 0.5);

    //var_dump('$jRounded: '.$jRounded);

    // oiInt kChange = (oiInt)logb(jRounded) - 12;
    $kChange = intval(log($jRounded, 2)) - 12;

    //var_dump('$kChange: '.$kChange);

    // k += kChange;
    $k += $kChange;


    //var_dump('$k 2: '.$k);

    // oiFloat64 jFloat = scalb(jRounded, kChange);
    $jFloat = $jRounded * pow(2, $kChange);

    //var_dump('$jFloat: '.$jFloat);

    $j = intval($jFloat);

    //var_dump('$j: '.$j);
    //var_dump('===============================');

    $intChecksum ^= $j;
    $intChecksum *= $TRIVIAL_CHECKSUM_MULT;
    $intChecksum &= 0xFFFFFFFF;

    $intChecksum ^= $k;
    $intChecksum *= $TRIVIAL_CHECKSUM_MULT;
    $intChecksum &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are the oi... types?

Comment: oiInt is a 32bit signed integer and oiFloat64 is a double float 64bit float. All the types where categorized by the author of the C++.

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup, @Jonathan !